# Create wall for post made of blocks

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

i need a way to create a wall made of blocks.
The idea was: i get the informations via php, then i echo them in a div.

```
Stylesheet
.block{
min-height:100px;
min-width:190px;
background-color:#999;
float:left;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-left:5px;
margin-right:5px;
}
.holder{
width:800px;
height:100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here the html:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class='holder'>
<? *connect to the db*
my_query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news");
while($array=mysql_fetch_array(my_query)){
echo "<div class='block' id='block_".$array['id']."'>".$array['text']."<div>";
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, the problem is that obviously the blocks have not the same height nor the same width, and so the float left create horrible margin between the blocks and the right side of the holder.

How they should be
http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/1813/cy44.png
How they display
http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/9703/lnyr.png
Ideas: For the width I could use jquery maybe creating id by echo.

```
if($('#block_'+id).css('width')>590){$('#block_'+id).css('width','790')}
if($('#block_'+id).css('width')>390){$('#block_'+id).css('width','590')}
if($('#block_'+id).css('width')>190){$('#block_'+id).css('width','390')}
```

This should do the trick for the width, but what about the height? Should i try to create a function set the absolute position of all the element based on the height of the element that are before?

Comment: Take a look at Masonry. This topic has been covered on SO before. Dig around a bit.

Comment: Thanks, i'm looking for it. Seems to be the perfect script!
Masonry should do the trick, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I not clearly understand your requirement. But you can do one thing set comman class for all elements say '.elements' and once rendered you can get all elements you can all elements like this below commands.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('.elements')  // and you do want you want to do.
```

})

Comment: I've set the common class block, but there could be more text in an element than in an other, so the element could enlarge. I don't need to edit all the element, i need to set the position of each one of them.

Comment: Hungerstar pointed out that already exist [Masonry][1]. It did the trick.


  [1]: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: @user2803734: You should post this as an answer and accept it so others can see that 
your problem was solved, especially if you solved it yourself :)

Comment: I have to wait more 21 hours to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Hungerstar pointed out that already exist [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). It did the trick.